# Merge sort infinite recursion

Tags: ruby, algorithm, mergesort

I haven't started the merge process yet. So far I've only focused on dividing the array over and over again until only 1 number is left in the array. Below is my code showing how I implemented this so far.

```
def mergesort(list)
  mid = list.length / 2
  left = list[0, mid]
  right = list[mid, list.size]
  until left.size <= 1 || right.size <= 1 do
    test(mergesort(left), mergesort(right))
  end
  print left
  print right
  def test(left, right)
    sorted = []
    left.length / 2
    right.length / 2
    # print sorted
  end
end
```

My problem is the loop will not break. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm also open to resources to help me solve this problem better. I would like some guidance in solving this issue that has arise.

Comment: Why would the loop break?

Answer (score 0):

Your looping is infinite. `left` and `right` are **not** changed later in a deeper step so they both remain bigger than 1.

```
until left.size <= 1 || right.size <= 1 do
    test(mergesort(left), mergesort(right))
end
```

#### How to fix this

One of the concepts that `merge-sort` uses is [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Those sorting algorithms use the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) instead, because it should work for any size. You should implement your [end condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination) in your recursive method. For example:

```
def mergesort(list)
  return list if array.size <= 1 # end condition
  mid = list.length / 2
  left = mergesort list[0, mid]
  right = mergesort list[mid, list.size]    

  print left
  print right

  # TODO merge left and right
end
```

As you can see we first do a merge sort on the first half recursively until the size of the array is smaller or equal to 1. Followed by the right part.